# Concatenate value in Jquery using Laravel framework to encrypt url

Tags: jquery, laravel, loops, encryption, concatenation

I'm developing a website with the Laravel framework and I m looking for a way to encrypt my url.

I do that with the method encrypt of the framework into a loop ($.each) of a JS Script but I can't retrieve the id value. When I try to do a vardump from my controller it shows me the string "id" and not the value of id (int). I think I did something wrong in concatenate, but after 2h to look towards without any result I come back here to ask your help

```
<a href="{!! url('/contact',Crypt::encrypt(' + id + ')) !!}" role="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Contact</a>
```

Comment: You cannot use javascript variables in php code, please read [this answer about the differences between server and client side programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171210/153671).

Comment: @Jerodev "id" is a js variable. I m using json_encode() to create the loop in JS and retrieve informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot inject javascript variables into PHP.

here is a suggestion you can try like this.

`<?php $somevariable =  url('/contact',Crypt::encrypt($someId)) ?>`

```
<a href="{!! $somevariable !!}" role="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Contact</a>
```

But you cannot use JS variable inside PHP.